# Is washing solar panels useful/needed/mandatory?

Tags: solar-power, photovoltaics, cleaning

Washing solar panels is sometimes recommended by some third party companies but it involves monetary and environmental costs.

Is it beneficial? I compared the ratio production over insolation the week before and after a friend washed his labels for the first time in 5 years and I couldn't see any meaningful difference.

Is it needed to ensure their long life? Are there studies about it?

And is it mandatory to ensure that insurances will pay in case of damage by fire? In my contract the insurance states that regular maintenance should be performed but there's nothing in the documentation by the company providing the panels about it.

Answer (score 3):

It really all depends on the local climate.
In dry regions, dust will build up over time on the panels and that will slowly have an effect on output.
In wet regions, like Ireland, the panels get washed far more than they need so other cleaning is unnecessary.
In hot, wet regions you can get growth in any part of the panel that retains water, i.e. where the laminate meets the aluminium frame, and if left uncleaned this will in time have an effect.

So I thinkg it would be rare that the panels need cleaning every year but definitely keep an eye out for dust buildup and/or growth.

Comment: Additionally, the angle that the solar panels are mounted at likely play a role - I think you want at least a 15 degree slope.